# $.get adds "HTTP/1.1" alongside with my variables in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, get

I used FireFox throughout all this time and didn't see that. But when I opened IE9 I saw that the **GET** request was not as I intended:

```
$.get("includes/processSub.php", choice, function(response){ 
 $('#subscriptionValueText').html(response);
});
```

So I have the request body like this:
(IE9 F12):

```
GET /MySite/includes/processSub.php?type=BRONZE_COST_1 HTTP/1.1
```

The added HTTP/1.1 is confusing my parser on the other end. 
Why is that ?

Comment: But [that's correct](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), isn't it? It should also have a `Host:` line too.

Comment: The HTTP/1.1 part is standard part of the request header. It's not the one that confuses the processSub.php.

Comment: Btw, you can see the request if you use firebug or Tamper Data (I think Tamapa Data is in this issue more comfortable to use)

Comment: I thought I am failing to process the $_GET array because of that....

Comment: What different result were you expecting? This is a basic part of the HTTP protocol and has been for many decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not adding that, that is a normal part of an HTTP request.  If you've got a server that doesn't understand it, that server is broken.  You can read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) to familiarise yourself with the HTTP protocol.

Comment: I have to say it is something related to IE9 or IE in general, apparently it held cache of that request, saying I had a problem in the php file (which I already changed) which led me to think the problem is that request. I cleaned the cache of IE and all is good, sorry for the trouble. and Thanks